# Building gcc on centos?

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, centos

I am trying to build gcc on cent os. I am trying to do exactly what this page writes: http://www.gnu.org/software/gsrc/

After installing python, bzr and a few other packages I managed to almost get it right, but on this step: `make -C gnu/hello`

I get those errors:

```
[root@localhost gsrc]# make -C gnu/hello
make: Entering directory `/root/gsrc/gnu/hello'
printf "[install-info] ==>Installing entries to the Info directory\n"
[install-info] ==>Installing entries to the Info directory
if /bin/sh -c 'install-info --version' >/dev/null; then \
        for f in hello.info; do \
            install-info --dir-file="/root/gnu/share/info/dir" \
                "/root/gnu/share/info/$f"; \
        done; \
    else true; fi
/root/gnu/share/info/dir: could not read (No such file or directory) and could not create (No such file or directory)
make: *** [post-install] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `/root/gsrc/gnu/hello'
```

Comment: Questions about how to compile open source projects are offtopic here.

Comment: why please and where can I ask this question?

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You'll probably have to ask the people that wrote the program/script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the information you gave, I suggest you just manually create the missing  directory:

```
mkdir -p /root/gnu/share/info/
```

and then rerun you make -C gnu/hello

This directory is where the info manager keeps its info files. But the fact that this directory is missing although the install-info prog is there suggest that something went wrong in your install

Comment: okay, i did this, I get the exact same error but instead of `/root/gnu/share/info/dir: could not read (No such file or directory) and could not create (No such file or directory)` I get `install-info: Is a directory for /root/gnu/share/info/dir`

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake: dir is not a directory(!), it's file. so delete the directory (rmdir /root/gnu/share/info/dir) and create the directory info in share (mkdir -p /root/gnu/share/info/). I think it will work. If so i'll modify my answer accordingly.

Comment: Also I think you should not operate as root. Create a simple user and use root only when needed because that could lead to unexpected and undesirable behaviours.

Comment: Doesn't completely solve what I am trying to do but game an idea.